# NodeJS|Cluster: how objects on message passing are handled?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am facing a problem with Node.JS and cluster. I want to write a program where the master cluster dispatches N tasks to worker clusters by sending a message to the worker. When a worker cluster completes his task it sends back a message to the master. The message sent by the worker is the same as the one that the worker received from the master, but the worker adds the result of its processing.

I am sharing the sample code I have used below. I am running Node on my Windows machine. The problem is that I would have expected that the worker can re-use the same message object received from master and add new properties, but as you can see from the output, this is not always the case.
I do not want to use any other mem cached SW like Redis, or whatsoever, since I would expect my code to work fine.

```
var os = require('os');
var cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    masterCluster();
} else {
    workerCluster();
}

function masterCluster()
{
    var taskList = [];
    var workerList = [];

    console.log(`[MASTER] Master process ${process.pid} is running`);
    // create 10 tasks
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        taskList.push({taskNo: i, timeoutMs: Math.floor(Math.random()*3000 + 500)});
    }
    var completedTasks = 0;

    // Fork workers
    for (var i=0; i<os.cpus().length; i++)
    {
        var worker = cluster.fork({workerId: i});
        worker.on('message', function(msg) {

            console.log('[MASTER] Master got a message from worker: ' + JSON.stringify(msg));
            if (completedTasks < taskList.length) {
                taskList[msg.taskNo] = msg;
                worker.send(taskList[completedTasks++]);
            }
            else {
                console.log(taskList)
                process.exit();
            }

        });
    }

}

function workerCluster()
{
    var workerInfo = {id: process.env.workerId, pid: process.pid};
    console.log('[Worker ', workerInfo, '] started');

    // Receive messages from the master process.
    process.on('message', function(msg) {
        console.log('[Worker ', workerInfo, '] got msg from master: ' + JSON.stringify(msg));

        setTimeout(function() {
            msg.data = {completed: true};
            process.send(msg);
        }, msg.timeoutMs);
    });

    process.send({});
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
[MASTER] Master process 19556 is running
[Worker  { id: '0', pid: 26992 } ] started
[Worker  { id: '1', pid: 27128 } ] started
[MASTER] Master got a message from worker: {}
[MASTER] Master got a message from worker: {}
[Worker  { id: '2', pid: 26576 } ] started
[MASTER] Master got a message from worker: {}
[Worker  { id: '3', pid: 52848 } ] started
[MASTER] Master got a message from worker: {}
[Worker  { id: '4', pid: 50916 } ] started
[MASTER] Master got a message from worker: {}
[Worker  { id: '5', pid: 63632 } ] started
[MASTER] Master got a message from worker: {}
[Worker  { id: '6', pid: 26284 } ] started
[Worker  { id: '7', pid: 21672 } ] started
[MASTER] Master got a message from worker: {}
[MASTER] Master got a message from worker: {}
[Worker  { id: '7', pid: 21672 } ] got msg from master: {"taskNo":0,"timeoutMs":653}
[Worker  { id: '7', pid: 21672 } ] got msg from master: {"taskNo":1,"timeoutMs":746}
[Worker  { id: '7', pid: 21672 } ] got msg from master: {"taskNo":2,"timeoutMs":1032}
[Worker  { id: '7', pid: 21672 } ] got msg from master: {"taskNo":3,"timeoutMs":2163}
[Worker  { id: '7', pid: 21672 } ] got msg from master: {"taskNo":4,"timeoutMs":595}
[Worker  { id: '7', pid: 21672 } ] got msg from master: {"taskNo":5,"timeoutMs":1570}
[Worker  { id: '7', pid: 21672 } ] got msg from master: {"taskNo":6,"timeoutMs":1220}
[Worker  { id: '7', pid: 21672 } ] got msg from master: {"taskNo":7,"timeoutMs":2882}
[MASTER] Master got a message from worker: {"taskNo":4,"timeoutMs":595,"data":{"completed":true}}
[Worker  { id: '7', pid: 21672 } ] got msg from master: {"taskNo":8,"timeoutMs":724}
[MASTER] Master got a message from worker: {"taskNo":0,"timeoutMs":653,"data":{"completed":true}}
[Worker  { id: '7', pid: 21672 } ] got msg from master: {"taskNo":9,"timeoutMs":3049}
[MASTER] Master got a message from worker: {"taskNo":1,"timeoutMs":746,"data":{"completed":true}}
[ { taskNo: 0, timeoutMs: 653, data: { completed: true } },
  { taskNo: 1, timeoutMs: 746 },
  { taskNo: 2, timeoutMs: 1032 },
  { taskNo: 3, timeoutMs: 2163 },
  { taskNo: 4, timeoutMs: 595, data: { completed: true } },
  { taskNo: 5, timeoutMs: 1570 },
  { taskNo: 6, timeoutMs: 1220 },
  { taskNo: 7, timeoutMs: 2882 },
  { taskNo: 8, timeoutMs: 724 },
  { taskNo: 9, timeoutMs: 3049 },
  undefined: {} ]
```

I would have expected that the list at the end contains all "data: {completed:true}" but this is present only on two entries.
If I re-run the code again and again I get the two entries in different positions, but always two.

Any help is very appreciated since I am struggling to find an explanation of this behavior.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your trying to do two jobs with one var `completedTasks`, your using this to decide when all task are done and what the next task is.  These will often not be the same.  Adding another var say called `nextTask` should help here.

Also doing `process.send({});` to kick start each cluster seems a bit hacky.

Instead I just created a new sub function called `addTask` that just gets called in 2 places,  1 inside your cluster init for each cpu, and again when a task has been completed.

In a nutshell, the way messages are sent in Clusters is likely the way you expect, your problem was a logic error instead.

Here is your modified Javascript

```
var os = require('os');
var cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    masterCluster();
} else {
    workerCluster();
}

function masterCluster()
{
    var taskList = [];

    console.log(`[MASTER] Master process ${process.pid} is running`);
    // create 10 tasks
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        taskList.push({taskNo: i, timeoutMs: Math.floor(Math.random()*3000 + 500)});
    }
    var completedTasks = 0;
    var nextTask = 0;

    function addTask() {
      if (nextTask < taskList.length) {
        worker.send(taskList[nextTask]);
        nextTask += 1;
      }
    }

    // Fork workers
    for (var i=0; i<os.cpus().length; i++)
    {
        var worker = cluster.fork({workerId: i});
        addTask();
        worker.on('message', function(msg) {
            console.log('[MASTER] Master got a message from worker: ' + JSON.stringify(msg));
            taskList[msg.taskNo] = msg;
            completedTasks += 1;
            addTask();
            if (completedTasks >= taskList.length) {
              console.log(taskList);
              process.exit();
            }
        });
    }

}

function workerCluster()
{
    var workerInfo = {id: process.env.workerId, pid: process.pid};
    console.log('[Worker ', workerInfo, '] started');
    // Receive messages from the master process.
    process.on('message', function(msg) {
        console.log('[Worker ', workerInfo, '] got msg from master: ' + JSON.stringify(msg));
        setTimeout(function() {
            msg.data = {completed: true};
            process.send(msg);
        }, msg.timeoutMs);
    });

}
```

Comment: Dear Keith, thanks a lot for your answer that clarifies my doubt and fixes the issue as well. The next doubt was if I could re-use in the worker the same message object received from the master, add new properties and send it back to the master. After seeing the code working I would assume it is possible. Also as far as I have understood, in case of passed messages a new object is created for every message, i.e.: no reference to the object is used in this case.

Comment: @yancheelo  ` i.e.: no reference to the object is used in this case.`  yes, your safe to use the `msg`, safe in the knowledge that it's not a reference.  From what I understand it can't be a reference, as passing references between processes is not possible.  IOW: think of messages as been `JSON.stringify` first.